# Pivotcache create runtime error mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have been trying to create a `PivotTabl`e using VBA, but it keeps giving me Pan error message in the `PivotCache` section.

I have three worksheets on a workbook and I intend to use the table in worksheet 1 to create a pivot table and chart on worksheet 3.  But I keep getting an error message.

Here is my vba code:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pc As PivotCaches
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook   

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A58")

    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination _
        :=Range("A58"), TableName:="PivotTable5", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14)

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

End Sub
```

*Pivot-Table Data screen-shot*

[image]

Comment: Is your "table" in "Sheet1" formatted as `Table` , which means in VBA `ListObject` ? Or do you mean a regular `Range` ?

Comment: @Shai Rado, Table1 is in Sheet1. i didnt change the name. It is simply Table1. I have not formatted in anyway. So, I believe it is in the default state.

Comment: you have not answered my question to what is Table1, is it the sheet's name, Table? Range? Can you edit your post and add a screenshot of your data ? A sample of it ?

Comment: @Shai Rado, I have just added a screenshot of my data. Yes my table is in Sheet 1. It is a Table. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PivotTablefromTable()

Dim wb          As Workbook
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim PTbl        As PivotTable
Dim PCache      As PivotCache
Dim WorkTbl     As ListObject
Dim PTblRng     As Range
Dim Rng         As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set Rng = ws.Range("A58")

Set WorkTbl = Worksheets("work").ListObjects("Table1") ' <-- set a variable to the "Table1" in sheet "work"
Set PTblRng = WorkTbl.Range '<-- get the range from "Table1"

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PTblRng)

' Set the Pivot Table (already created in previous macro run)
On Error Resume Next
Set PTbl = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5")

On Error GoTo 0
If PTbl Is Nothing Then ' <-- pivot table still doesn't exist >> need to create it
    ' create a new Pivot Table in ws sheet, start from Cell A58
    Set PTbl = ws.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=Rng, TableName:="PivotTable5")

    ' rest of your code here

Else ' just refresh the Pivot table, with updated Pivot Cache
    PTbl.ChangePivotCache PCache
    PTbl.RefreshTable
End If

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

End Sub
```